# How to select the most recent data from SQL joining 3 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have 3 tables.  I need to join the (AGENT table) from (DATA table) by column RANKDATA.  There may be multiple entries in the DATA table.  I need to select the most recent based on the DATE, then get the CODE_ID and join in CODE table.

[image: problem]

Here's my code.  I tried to use `Max(D.DATE)` but I got an error.  My only problem, I don't know how to group it by the most recent date.

```
select A.ID, A.NAME, C.CODE_NAME, D.DATE
from Agent A
JOIN Data D ON A.RANKDATA = D.RANKDATA
JOIN CODE C ON D.CODE_ID = C.CODE_ID
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWepb.png)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or, even worse, links to images.) And no need to use UPPER CASE like that.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: `Max(D.DATE)` is a good start. Add `GROUP BY the other selected columns` at the end of your query.

Comment: i use sql server

Comment: I try to use max() but i got this error "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: You can't just use JOIN DATA  D because you only want to use the most recent row. So use JOIN (select RANKDATA, CODE_ID, DATE 
from DATA
group by RANKDATA
having DATE = max(DATE)) D

Comment: im sorry can you please give me the syntax where should i put that line..

Comment: i try but i dont get the right syntax.. sorry

Comment: Don't you recognize JOIN DATA D from your own statement above? I just gave you a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what your results are supposed to be from your image, bu t an alternative to doing this with a `group by` might be to use `row_number`. `row_number` basically projects a column with an incrementing integer (1,2,3,...n) over your rows. You can "partition" the function in the same way you would a group by. In this case, I partitioned it by `a.RankData`, but that was sort of a guess at what you wanted. The `order by` defines in what order the row numbering will appear. In this case, I've ordered it by `d.[date]` descending so the most recent date for every `a.RankData` will be the number 1. Finally, I turn all that into a subquery so I can put the new column in a `where` clause and just skim off those where `RID = 1` (i.e the date is the max date).

```
select *
from (select 
          RID = row_number() over(partition by a.RankData order by d.[date] desc),
          A.ID, 
          A.NAME, 
          C.CODE_NAME, 
          D.DATE
      from Agent A
      inner join [Data] D 
          on A.RANKDATA = D.RANKDATA
      inner join CODE C 
          on D.CODE_ID = C.CODE_ID) a
where a.RID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a CROSS APPLY, as an additional option.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, T.CODE_NAME, T.DATE
FROM Agent A
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 C.CODE_NAME, D.DATE
        FROM
            Data D JOIN CODE C ON D.CODE_ID = C.CODE_ID
            WHERE A.RANKDATA = D.RANKDATA 
            ORDER BY D.DATE DESC) T
```

An image helps to visualize. But if you need time from others to help you, it would definitely be useful if you include a simple script to create your test data: 
Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Agent (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(30) ,RANKDATA INT)
INSERT INTO Agent
VALUES (1,'Mark',12), (2,'Joe',13), (3,'Steve',11), (4,'Sam',10)

CREATE TABLE DATA (ID int, RANKDATA int, CODE_ID VARCHAR(2), DATE datetime)
INSERT INTO DATA
VALUES (1,12,'01','20170901 2:30'), (2,13,'02','20170901 6:30'), 
        (3,11,'03','20170901 4:30'), (4,10,'02','20170901 1:30'), 
        (5,10,'03','20170901 2:50'), (6,12,'02','20170901 5:30')

CREATE TABLE CODE(ID int, CODE_ID varchar(2), CODE_NAME Varchar(15))
INSERT INTO CODE
VALUES (1,'01','RANK 1'), (2,'02','RANK 2'), (3,'03','RANK 3')
```